# Overhauling and painting upvc door handles

Tags: doors, painting, hardware

I wish to overhaul some of my exterior door handles in uPVC frames.

[Handle images](https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=14Wc4ylokGXGCYwEWlzS35Kem4_D153vl)

[image]

1. What paint do I use to "touch up" the scratches and gouges in the white paintwork?
2. How to I fix the loose handle where the washer is showing?

3.Is there any spray paint I can use to cover the gold painted handle with a silver/grey colour?

Comment: Unfortunately, despite your effort and a potentially nice immediate outcome, no common spray paint will be durable enough to give you more than a few months service without looking worn itself. Unless you can do a baked powdercoat, for example, I don't recommend this project. Replacement hardware would be a better bet.

Comment: Can you link the product page for the door handle in question?